# Resetting mat radio group state on new bound value

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I'm building a kind of question answering app. We have a bunch of questions and the user should be able to answer them one by one while there is always just one question on the screen.
Changing between questions is done by routing via a route param passed to a question component.
Inside the component template, I have a mat radio group to display the different answer options (always the values "1", "2" and "3").

When I now answer one question and move to next one, the mat radio button group keeps the state from the previous question answer. I do want to reset the state here. So the next question is not answered already (no radio button selected and also none focused).
I was playing around with resetting the checked state in the radio button change handler, but that seems like a hacky workaround and also does not work well (I can not check off the same answer again -> causes no change event).

**Does anyone have an idea, how to implement that use case properly?**

**Constraints**

- The current question for the given route is pulled from a facade as observable. This should stay like it is. There is a ngrx store behind the facade which handles all state management logic.
- Saving the question answer has to be done via a method call on the facade.

I'd be glad for any tips and tricks 
Here is a stackblitz, which roughly shows the problem: [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fypksg?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/question/question.component.ts)

Comment: If the updated answer solves your issue can you please mark it as accepted

Comment: Jep. I will. It looks good. I wanted to check it with my existing code first to see, if I missed any important parts. Will then mark it as accepted. Sorry for the delay. Will take a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things going on here, I'll split them up by file.

#### The Component

The biggest thing is there's no need for `question$` to be a `BehaviorSubject`, it can simply be a variable of `{ question: string, answer: string }`. If you wanted to get fancy you could define a type for it:

```js
type Question = {
  question: string;
  answer: string;
};
```

So `question$` turns into:

```js
public question: Question;
```

With this change, the route subscription looks like this:

```js
this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
  // ...Maps and Filter all the same...
).subscribe((questionNumber) => {

  const question = this.allQuestions[questionNumber - 1];
  const answer = this.answers[question];

  this.question = { question, answer };
});
```

*(Tip: The `tap` was a bit redundant here, I moved its logic into the `subscribe` for simplicity, it behaves in exactly the same way )*

With `question` in this form, to update it we simply need to update the value and Angular will pick up that change and update the template accordingly. This ends up simplifying the template too.

#### The Template

With `question` just being a field, the `*ngIf` becomes simply `*ngIf="question"`.

The biggest change on the template is the data binding syntax. `mat-radio-group` is a Form element and the way Angular binds form values to a Component field is with `ngModel`. Specifically you want to use it with the "banana in a box" `[( )]` [Two-way Binding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding) syntax that means changes in the Template will update the Component value and vice versa.

So the template ends up looking like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="question">
  <div>{{ question.question }}</div>
  <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="question.answer">    <!--  Magic happens here  -->
    <mat-radio-button value="1">1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="2">2</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="3">3</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
  <button (click)="goNext()">Go next</button>
</ng-container>
```

The `value` fields should be on the `mat-radio-button`s. That's the data that actually gets assigned `question.answer` when one of the options get selected.

And that's it!  Here's [the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wxiasm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion%2Fquestion.component.ts) with some additional added logging to show the state of `answers`.

### *Update*

Taking in the constraints from the updated question, keeping `question$` as an Observable, the template should look like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="question$ | async as question">
  <div>{{ question.question }}</div>
  <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="question.answer">
    <mat-radio-button value="1">1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="2">2</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="3">3</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
  <button (click)="goNext(question)">Go next</button>
</ng-container>
```

Using this method the facade method call to save the answer can then be made inside `goNext()`.

Updated [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-npkxnj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion%2Fquestion.component.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. 
The stackblitz was a very basic reproduction. It left out some things, which are important to know. I just wanted to keep it short.

1. I'm actually pulling the questions from a facade as Observable.
2. I'm using change detection OnPush to avoid performance drawbacks. Therefore, I do not want to directly bind fields.
3. I need a callback function to change the state in the facade via a method call.

With these things in mind, do you see an alternative approach? I updated the Stackblitz a bit, but it does not seem to work yet.

Comment: I'll update the question to make that clearer.

Comment: @pascalbe ah yep the old case of [Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#:~:text=on%20Stack%20Overflow.-,Complete,-Make%20sure%20all) suffering at the hands of [Minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#:~:text=minimal%2C%20reproducible%20example.-,Minimal,-The%20more%20code). Those new constraints do change things, I've added an update to my answer with an updated StackBlitz :)